# Too much space in loop

Tags: visual-studio-code

Did I mess with the setting or is this a new feature?

[image: Picture 1 One day ago]

[image: Picture 2 Today]

Comment: I'm guessing your bottom tool bar says "Spaces: 8"? Click on it and set it to "Indent using spaces" and then 4.

Comment: You right. Tnx for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have changed your tab indentation value. Look at the status bar (bottom right) and see how many spaces your tab is set to. You can click on the status bar to change it, or press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (OS X) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (Windows) to open the command pallete and type `Indent` to find the `Indent Using Spaces` option and set it to `4` (or `8`, whatever you like).